# Alchemist potion on Undead

Tags: werewolv.es

When an Alchemist uses their non-coven potion on other factions, then a Wolfpack member will become either a normal Werewolf or a Shape Shifter, and a Village member will become either a Villager, Lycan, Sleepwalker, Insomniac, or Stalker.  Vampires and familiars are not affected by the potion.

But if an Alchemist targets an Undead player with their purge potion, what role does the Undead player become?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Undead player will become either a Wight or a Ghoul.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, believe it or not, but an undead purged by the alchemist was once turned into a villager role. Would love to hear an update from the mods if this no long happens anymore.

Source: A spud I hosted long ago. Can't remember the number right now, but I'll update the answer once I check the archives.

Comment: This used to be the case, but it should be updated to the mechanism described in my answer now! :)

Comment: Indeed. I am against having mechanics that can turn an evil player into a villager, because they could completely sell out their former team, and it somewhat negates the point of playing the game

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll share the spud number if anyone's still interested: arc-110.